# How to run SQL script in React Native app on SQLite database?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to combine data from two applications. One is written in C# Windows Forms and is a database, the other that accepts data is written in React Native. The Forms application runs on Firebird, while the React Native application runs on SQLite.

I generated an SQL file from the WinForms application with data to be imported into the SQLite database. My problem is that in React Native using react-native-sqlite-storage, I can run queries written in SQL, but I can't run a script that will insert data into the application.